# Webview and javascript use

Tags: android

Hi Im trying to get a certain variable value from a local HTML page. The function simply returns the value of a simple variable called x ( x is set to 5 ) so I want to call this function in android. Here is my code so far:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSaveFormData( false );
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/tester.html" );

    getScript = (Button) findViewById( R.id.test );
    getScript.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:getX()" );
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText( this, "Hello World", duration );
}
```

So the idea is that when the getScript button is called it calls the function on the HTML page but how would i get that value displayed? Like in the toast message below it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: Add a `WebChromeClient` to your `WebView`, implement `onJSAlert()` in the `WebChromeClient`, and have your JavaScript code use `alert()`

Option #2: Add a custom JavaScript->Java bridge object to WebKit via `addJavaScriptInterface()`, and have your JavaScript code call something on that object

Comment: Thanks mate I'll have to do some research on it all - just seems to be bait complicated at this point

Comment: Hello all - Thought I'd leave a great link here that clarified my javascript/webview issues - http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/JavascriptBridge The only difference I did was to not load my stuff on the onResume() method. Cheers again CommonsWare